# How can I reference a string that is in a yaml file via javascript in a rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yaml

Do I need to install something to get this to work?

I have a Rails App that utilizes views writen in haml with a few javascript-based widgets here and there.

I've abstracted all of the strings in the haml file by referencing the en.yml file. (soon there will be a yml file for each language which is very exciting!)

The only strings left are the ones in the javascript widgets. How can I abstract those? Is there a syntax? Do I need a gem? I don't really know how to look this up because I'm not sure if I'm describing this in the proper programming terms.

Comment: javascript yaml parser you need to parse yaml and get the string using js..https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/blob/master/README.md  <script src="js-yaml.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var doc = jsyaml.load('greeting: hello\nname: world');
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pre-process any of your javascript files, just append `.erb` or `.haml` to the file name.

For example, if you have something like this:

```
// app/assets/javascript/main.js
console.log('some text');
```

You could localize it like this:

```
// app/assets/javascript/main.js.erb
console.log("<%= j I18n.t('some.text') %>");

// config/locales/en.yml
en:
  some:
    text: Some text
```

Alternatively, you may take a look at [this gem](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js).

Comment: I'm going to try this out today. Thanks!! (Sorry for the holiday lag thanking you)

Comment: I will comment with results once I have tested this, in the meantime, I'm going to assume you are correct. Thanks!!

Comment: you need to use the javascript escape/quoting helper, otherwise your text (if containing `"`) will produce an error

Comment: you are right, I have corrected the answer. More reference on javascript escaping can be found here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9505a21f425e37e54426120849e3ca2a494cc7b0/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb#L25